# How to pass posted data in form of a variable to function?

Tags: php, wordpress, authorize.net

I am developing an API and I want to send some PHP variables with the posted data through to the API. So far this is how it's working:

```
$firstName  = $_POST['first_name'];
$lastName   = $_POST['last_name'];
$cardNumber = $_POST['order_payment_number'];
$oldExpirationDate = $_POST['order_payment_expire_month'] . $_POST['order_payment_expire_year'];
$date = date('m/d/Y', strtotime('+01 months'));
$expirationDate = substr($oldExpirationDate, 2);
```

When I actually place these variables inside of functions though, the code breaks. Example:

```
    $subscription->setName("Sample Name"); //sends to API perfectly
    $subscription->setName($firstName); //Hits an error, does not submit
```

However when I echo the variables, they print just fine.

```
echo $firstName; //returns stored data in $_POST['first_name'];
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: It's just an internal error that is built into the API from Authorize. E00014: A required field is not present.

Comment: ok can you please try one with the  (string)$firstName

Comment: What do you mean? What's posted into $firstName is always a string.

Comment: Looking at the API the only examples I can find are: $merchantAuthentication->setName(\SampleCode\Constants::MERCHANT_LOGIN_ID); meaning that you are trying to use a variable instead of a constant thus the error. Are you sure that you are using the right API call? http://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/index.html#payment-transactions-charge-a-credit-card

Comment: Yes I'm 100% positive, I've actually solved the problem thanks.